# how to connect to samba server running in docker

Tags: docker, samba, smb

I am running Docker Version 17.09.0-ce-mac35 on mac. I want to have a samba server running as part of a docker container and then connect to the running samba server from my mac. I'm using https://github.com/dperson/samba for this.

I run the samba server like this:

```
➜  ~ sudo docker run -it -p 139:139 -p 445:445  -v /Users/anthony:/mount -d dperson/samba \
            -u "example1;badpass" \
            -u "example2;badpass" \
            -s "public;/share" \
            -s "users;/srv;no;no;no;example1,example2" \
            -s "example1 private;/example1;no;no;no;example1" \
            -s "example2 private;/example2;no;no;no;example2"
```

I can bash into the container and see all my files in `/mount`. However, when I try to connect to the samba server from mac in Finder > Go > Connect to server I get an error while connecting. I've tried the following:

```
smb://0.0.0.0
smb://localhost
smb://0.0.0.0/public
smb://localhost/public
smb://<docker_ip>/
smb://<docker_ip>/public
```

None of them work. Is there something I'm missing? Or is there another way to get a smb share running on a mac for test/playing around?

Comment: Did you try setting the capabilities SYS_ADMIN and DAC_READ_SEARCH like explained here https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22197?

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect using the Samba user and local hostname:
smb://example1@localhost

Comment: I did the same and still problem. It was working but suddenly after once system restart it is not

Answer (score -3):

You forget the port.

Try `smb://ip:139/public`

Comment: You only need to supply the port if you are using a non-default port. The default CIFS (smb over IP) ports are 139 and 445.